# Save .webp images atuomatically as .jpeg/jpg images, when adding/saving web pages directly to onenote

Tags: microsoft-onenote, webp

I have searched across since last few days, but could not find a solution.
I want to save web pages which displays images as .webp converting those to .jpg automatically and send to OneNote app.

At present it is quite tedious to go and convert each and every webp image to jpg first and then edit the same again in OneNote, takes lot of time for webpages with many webp images.

Is there any solution where .webp image extension can be automatically converted to .jpg/png etc. when the webpage is displayed and those webp images can get displayed in one note as jpg/png etc. (as these are supported by onenote) ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use for faster conversation application https://products.aspose.app/imaging/conversion

and after conversion use app https://products.aspose.app/note/conversion to convert your image to onenote.

best regards
Oleg K.